# Proof Norm is Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Someone just asked me why the norm of a normed space is continuous, and the answer I gave them satisfied them, but I'm not sure if it should. Something seems amiss.

Let $\rho: X \to \mathbb{R}^+_0$ be a norm on a vector space $X$. Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}$ be open. Then let $$\rho^{-1}(U) = \{x \in X : \rho(x) \in U\}$$
Consider $y \in \rho^{-1}(U)$ so that $\rho(y) \in U$. Since $U$ is open, there exists $\epsilon >0$ so that $B_\epsilon(\rho(y)) \subset U$ or so that $(\rho(y) - \epsilon, \rho(y)+\epsilon) \subset U$. Now, set $$z = \frac{\epsilon y}{\rho(y)}$$ so that $(\rho(y) - \rho(z),\rho(y)+\rho(z)) \subset U$. By definition of norm (triangle inequalities), $$(\rho(y-z), \rho(y+z)) \subset (\rho(y) - \rho(z),\rho(y)+\rho(z)) \subset U$$ Thus, $(y-z,y+z) \subset \rho^{-1}(U)$. Since $y \in \rho^{-1}(U)$ was arbitrary, we can find a neighborhood around each point completely contained in the inverse set, so $\rho$ is continuous.

Am I missing something?

Comment: $| \|x\|-\|y\| | \le \|x-y\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks good to me! Another way to prove the continuity of $\rho$ is by taking a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $X$ converges to $x$, and show that $\rho(x_n) \rightarrow \rho(x)$ (use triangle inequality!)

Comment: Nguyen This was one of my concerns. How do we define convergence in $X$?

Comment: I think the standard definition is $x_n \rightarrow x$ in $X$ if $\rho(x_n-x) \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: We say that a sequence ${x_n}$ converges to $x$ in $X$, where X is normed vector space if and only if $\|x_n-x\|\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Ah, see this seems odd to prove continuity of a norm, using a norm for convergence. I had thought of this, but it seemed almost roundabout. Hence the reason for my unnecessarily long answer. I understand the validity now though.

Comment: @AnthonyPeter Notice that you're also using the norm to prove its continuity, because the neighbourhood is only a neighbourhood in the topology induced by the norm.